# Inserver distance calculation and Combining Neo4j queries

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have two queries which needs to be executed simultaneously on the neo4j server.
The first query needs to calculate the distance.
The Second Query needs to send the informations+ calculated distance in the JSON response
Pls suggest me How i could combine the  mentioned queries in Neo4j  ?

**QUERY1:**

=======

```
WITH point({ longitude:76.91859, latitude:8.487992, height: 100 }) AS p1, point({ latitude:8.495548 , longitude:76.93015, height: 100 }) AS p2 RETURN distance(p1,p2) AS dist
```

## QUERY2:

```
  MATCH (qperson:QuarantinedPersons) 
    WHERE qperson.name = 'Raman' 
    CREATE (thereturnrecord:theDetails{theid: qperson.id,thename: 
    qperson.Name,thedetails:qperson.details,thelat:qperson.lat,thelong:qperson.long,thedistance:2000}) 
   RETURN thereturnrecord
```

## Expected Output,similar to:

```
 [
      {
        "thereturnrecord": {
         "identity": 3,
         "labels": [
            "theDetails"
          ],
          "properties": {
        "thelong": "76.91859",
        "thelat": "8.487992",
        "thedetails": "XYZ",
        "thedistance": 2000(Obtained from the query),
        "theid": "1"
      }
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

[UPDATED]

Here is a combined query:

```
WITH
  point({ longitude:76.91859, latitude:8.487992, height: 100 }) AS p1,
  point({ latitude:8.495548 , longitude:76.93015, height: 100 }) AS p2
MATCH (q:QuarantinedPersons) 
WHERE q.name = 'Raman' 
CREATE (thereturnrecord:theDetails{
  theid: q.id,
  thename: q.Name,
  thedetails: q.details,
  thelat: q.lat,
  thelong: q.long,
  thedistance: distance(p1, p2)
}) 
RETURN thereturnrecord
```

Of, if the arguments for the 2 `point`s are passed as the [parameters](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/syntax/parameters/) `p1` and `p2`:

```
MATCH (q:QuarantinedPersons) 
WHERE q.name = 'Raman' 
CREATE (thereturnrecord:theDetails{
  theid: q.id,
  thename: q.Name,
  thedetails: q.details,
  thelat: q.lat,
  thelong: q.long,
  thedistance: distance(point($p1), point($p2))
}) 
RETURN thereturnrecord
```

Comment: it is ending with the error. RETURN can only be used at the end of the query (line 4, column 3 (offset: 149))
"  RETURN distance(p1, p2) AS dist" 
   ^